# Yii2 - Table alias with ActiveRecord

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a table with a long name, example `products_with_a_long_name`. The Model name is `ProductsWithALongName`. 
Now, I have a query where I need to select many columns from this table while joining with another table. Example:

```
ProductsWithALongName::find()
    ->select(['products_with_a_long_name.id', 'products_with_a_long_name.selling_price','client.name'])
    ->leftjoin('all_the_clients as client','products_with_a_long_name.clientId = client.id')
    ->where(['products_with_a_long_name.id' => $var]);
```

Now how can I use an alias for the first table, `products_with_a_long_name` as I'm using an alias for the second. I know I can use `Query` but in this case I need the result to be `ActiveRecord` so this is not an option in this case.

Comment: Try use ->alias('your_alias') after find

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`alias()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#alias()-detail):

```
ProductsWithALongName::find()
    ->alias('p')
    ->select(['p.id', 'p.selling_price','client.name'])
    ->leftjoin('all_the_clients as client', 'p.clientId = client.id')
    ->where(['p.id' => $var]);
```