# Yii2. Multiple innerJoinWith with one column renaming

Tags: join, activerecord, yii2

Trying to join relations tables. Everything work fine, except one thing. As result I have two similar column names. But i have no idea, how to rename one column from related 'stores' table inside query.

```
$query = StoreItem::find()->innerJoinWith('stores', true)->innerJoinWith('users', true);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
]);
```

Approciate any help.

Comment: Where are `similar` column names? I see `stores` and `users` - no ambiguity there. Possibly similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474661/yii2-table-alias-with-activerecord.

Comment: `Stores` and `users` are related.    Example:

public function getStores()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Store::classname(), ['id' => 'store_id']);`
    }
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::classname(), ['id' => 'publisher_id']);
    }

But inside `StoreItem::find()` i have similar 'column' name, as inside `stores `table

Comment: You just use alias to differentiate tables. By default main table in SQL is always aliased `t`, so you only need to set alias for joined table `users AS u` - see similar question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an alias to the tables and specify the columns that you want in the query. It would be like:

```
$query = StoreItem::find()->select('us.desiredcolumn, st.desiredcolumn')->innerJoinWith('stores as st', true)->innerJoinWith('users as us', true);
```

I don't know if it works, but it was an idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can create special relation with store:

```
public function getStoresSpec()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Stores::tableName(), ['id' => 'store_id'])->select('column as another_column', ...);
}
```

Here you set 'column' alias to 'another_column'. Don't forget to add all other fields you need for this relation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use alias like this:

```
$query = StoreItem::find()
    ->alias('si')
    ->innerJoinWith('stores', true)->innerJoinWith('users', true);
```

or define alias in your models like this:

```
public function getUserOrdersItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserOrdersItems::className(), ['user_orders_id' => 'id'])->alias('orderItems');
}
```

it is just example. You have to work with your 3 models.

Comment: As I understood, TS needs column alias, not table alias.

Comment: He get a error, because relations are the same name in different models